# PHP 'If' not working

Tags: php, variables

Basically I am trying to check if a variable is equal to 5, and then echo something if it is, but I get this error.

PHP Code

```
if ($adminlevel) === '5' {
    echo 'user is owner';
}
```

Error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '===' (T_IS_IDENTICAL) in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\Portfolio -- Website\forum\index.php on line 12
```

Comment: Move the closing paren after the '5'

Comment: See the manual on [`if`](http://php.net/if). Conditions belong **in** the parens.

Comment: April fools was 4 days ago. (`if ($adminlevel) === '5'` really? Just move your bracket behind the 5!)

Comment: You have to delete the post! Not we

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($adminlevel === '5') {
    echo 'user is owner';
}
```

Move the paren to include the entire statement.

Comment: How where you able to post an answer?

Comment: probably he got response late from the server, so answer submited or something